Unable to start my web-app in Azure App service because of Azure monitor opentelemetry SDK trying to create logs in /var/log/ directory
I am deploying a python based web-app on Azure App service. This is docker image which is being pulled from Azure container registry.
The problem is coming from inside the Azure Monitor OpenTelmetry SDK. The sdk creates log files for diagnostic logging within the following directory : /var/log/applicationinsights/ (for linux based web apps). This can be seen from the following code from the above sdk. This File path has been hardcoded in the sdk and is not configurable. I start the app using an app_user, which has access to the app related volumes in the container but not to the above directory.
 if not exists(_DIAGNOSTIC_LOG_PATH):
        makedirs(_DIAGNOSTIC_LOG_PATH)
    f_handler = logging.FileHandler(
        join(
            _DIAGNOSTIC_LOG_PATH, _DIAGNOSTIC_LOGGER_FILE_NAME
        )
    )
              

Due to this the App does not start with the following stacktrace:
2024-10-25T04:33:34.877284066Z File "/usr/src/app/api/main.py", line 19, in <module> 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.877309466Z configure_azure_telemetry(option="basic") 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.877361967Z File "/usr/src/app/api/dependencies/instrumentation.py", line 11, in configure_azure_telemetry 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.877378367Z configure_basic_azure_monitor() 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.877383767Z File "/usr/src/app/doc_generator_api/dependencies/instrumentation.py", line 25, in configure_basic_azure_monitor 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.878324584Z configure_azure_monitor( 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879013896Z File "/agents/python/azure/monitor/opentelemetry/_configure.py", line 98, in configure_azure_monitor 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879018996Z _send_attach_warning() 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879022896Z File "/agents/python/azure/monitor/opentelemetry/_configure.py", line 222, in _send_attach_warning 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879026897Z AzureDiagnosticLogging.warning( 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879030297Z File "/agents/python/azure/monitor/opentelemetry/_diagnostics/diagnostic_logging.py", line 87, in warning 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879034197Z AzureDiagnosticLogging._initialize() 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879037997Z File "/agents/python/azure/monitor/opentelemetry/_diagnostics/diagnostic_logging.py", line 68, in _initialize 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879041897Z f_handler = logging.FileHandler( 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879883312Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879896112Z File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 1181, in __init__ 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879905312Z StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open()) 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879910112Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879914512Z File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 1213, in _open 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879919112Z return open_func(self.baseFilename, self.mode, 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879923612Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
2024-10-25T04:33:34.879928513Z PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/applicationinsights/applicationinsights-extension.log'



I have tried giving the permissions of the above directory to the app_user in my dockerfile, but that does not seem to work :
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/applicationinsights

# Set the permissions to allow writing
RUN chown -R ${APP_UID}:${APP_GID} /var/log/applicationinsights
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/log/applicationinsights

Even after doing this the directory: /var/log/applicationinsights/ is still owned by root in Azure app service. Check attached image.

please provide your code that you've tried

provide your dockerfile

The error message you're encountering Permission denied means that the Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry SDK is trying to create log files in the /var/log/applicationinsights/ directory. This directory is set in the SDK and can't be changed.
Since your app is running as a non-root user app_user, it doesn’t have permission to write to that directory.

To resolve the issue, I've created a custom log directory at /home/logs in the application. So, that it can be accessed by the non-root user app_user.
I've created a link from /var/log/applicationinsights to /home/logs, this will redirect logs that the open telemetry SDK tried to write to /var/log/applicationinsights into custom log directory.
Added the below lines in my dockerfile

RUN  mkdir  -p  /home/logs  &&  \
ln  -sf  /home/logs  /var/log/applicationinsights

My complete Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install Flask azure-monitor-opentelemetry
RUN mkdir -p /home/logs && \
    ln -sf /home/logs /var/log/applicationinsights
RUN useradd -m app_user && \
    chown -R app_user:app_user /home/logs
USER app_user
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "main.py"]

Now my application starts without any errors

Logstream:

Here, the file permissions rwxrwxrwx show that all users have read, write, and execute permissions, which means the application user can write logs without permission issues.

